# Is there a way to use @see and friends in RDoc?

Tags: ruby, documentation, rdoc

JavaDoc and the like have a way to use `@see` (the "see also" tag) to link code or add links to external websites. Is there an equivalent in RDoc? Or is the best option just a list of links using `{Link text}[http://example.com/]`?

Comment: RDoc is just one tool. There's others like [Yard](https://yardoc.org) that might be worth exploring.

Comment: I might switch to YARD... RDoc seemed to be more standard / widely used which is why I selected it